# "Missing parameter type" in overloaded generic method taking a function argument

Tags: generics, scala, overloading, type-inference

I am having a problem in my DSL with overloaded generic methods resulting in the compiler wanting me to add explicit parameter types:

```
def alpha[T](fun: Int => T): String = fun(33).toString

def beta [T](fun: Int => T): String = fun(66).toString
def beta [T](thunk:   => T): String = thunk.toString

alpha { _ + 11 }          // ok
beta { _ + 22 }           // "error: missing parameter type for expanded function"
beta { _: Int => _ + 22 } // ok... ouch.
```

Any chance I can get rid of the the clutter in the last line?

**EDIT:**

To demonstrate that the overloading is not an ambiguity problem to scalac per se, here is a version without type parameter which works perfectly fine:

```
def beta(fun: Int => String): String = fun(66).reverse
def beta(thunk:   => String): String = thunk.reverse

beta(_.toString)  // ok
beta("gaga")      // ok
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `Int => T` is also a type. For example, say you defined just the second `beta`:

```
def beta[ T ]( thunk: => T ) : String = thunk.toString
```

And now you pass a function `Int => Int` to it:

```
scala> beta((_: Int) + 1)
res0: String = <function1>
```

So, given that a function fits `=> T`, and that you *also* have an `Int => T`, how is Scala supposed to know which one you want? It could be a `String`, for instance:

```
scala> beta((_: String) + 11)
res1: String = <function1>
```

How could Scala assume it was an `Int`? The examples you have shown to demonstrate overload isn't to blame don't demonstrate any such thing, because you got rid of the type parameters in them.

Answer (score 1):

As you might have realized, the issue occurs because you have beta function is overloaded. 
When you define:

```
beta { _ + 22 }
```

which beta do you expect it do call? Scala cannot know that `_` is an `Int` just because you are summing it with 22. So for this particular example, you have to define what `_` is.

Comment: Yes it can, because the argument is Int => T. Scalac knows that in the case of `alpha`, why doesn't it know it in the case of `beta`?

Comment: Because `beta` is overloaded, and there are two choices, one of which takes `Int => T` and another which takes `=> T`. That's why it is impossible to tell which of these you are referring to without telling it explicitly. Alpha works exactly because there is only once choice.

Comment: That is not true. It is a defect that is a result from having a type parameter. There is no ambiguity whether I call the thunk or the function version if the method is not generic. I have edited the question to show this.