# Thunk vs Function overload

Tags: scala

I want to define an overloaded method, one that accepts a function0, and one that accepts a function1, viz:

```
def produces(f: Context => Any): Processor = ...

def produces(thunk: => Any): Processor = ...
```

This compiles fine because the first is compiled to use a Function1 and the second to use a Function0, however the issue arises when I want to invoke, thus:

```
produces {
 ctx => "hello"
}
```

Gives me an

> missing parameter type

There's only one parameter that accepts an input, so why can't it infer.

Any tips on what I can do to get around this (other than rename one of the methods :))

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6448444/missing-parameter-type-in-overloaded-generic-method-taking-a-function-argument

Comment: Not the same thing really.

Comment: @monkjack I'd say it's deceptively close actually. How is it supposed to know after the _first_ string argument which curried function definition you're setting up to call next?

Comment: Ok I see. I don't know what the curried parameter groups gets complied into, but would have thought the 2nd parameter in the invocation was enough for inference?

Answer (score 2):

It's kind of silly-looking, but you can (awkwardly) help out the compiler's search strategy by requiring an implicit conversion for the I-can-take-anything-by-name version:

```
object Test {
  implicit def low_priority_conversion(t: Test.type) = LowPriority
  object LowPriority {
    def produces(x: => Any) : Boolean = false
  }
  def produces(f: String => Any): Boolean = true
}
```

Whether you `import Test._` or not, you'll find you have the correct behavior:

```
scala> Test.produces("fish")
res0: Boolean = false

scala> Test.produces(_.length)
res1: Boolean = true

scala> import Test._
import Test._

scala> produces("fish")
res2: Boolean = false

scala> produces(_.length)
res3: Boolean = true
```

Comment: This looks promising, but I cannot get it to work even if I have the implicit in the same class. Does this only work on objects->objects?

Comment: @monkjack - If it is a `class` instead of an `object`, you need to put the implicit def into the companion object.  Otherwise I'm not sure what you're doing so I can't tell why it doesn't work.

Comment: I've had a play about and your trick only works when you qualify the method invocation, eg with an object or this. In my case the methods are part of a trait that is mixed in. I cannot get it to work for this scenario.

Comment: @monkjack  - This is an answer to the question you asked, though.  Maybe you should be explicit about the required scenario in your question?

Answer (score 0):

I think the real answer here is, "don't do that"! ;-) The argument you're passing is actually valid for both your functions. The only reason you got an error rather than having the compiler silently call the "wrong"/unexpected function is because it couldn't infer the type for `ctx` (which is only because Scala's type inferrer doesn't support unification (yet)).

Basically, your problem is that `Any` is a supertype of `Context => Any`.

If you really want to name both functions the same, an alternative is to make one of them take a thunk as an argument rather than a pass-by-name `Any`. (But then you'd need to thunk any arguments you want to pass to the thunk version rather than having it implicitly evaluated lazily.)

For example:

```
scala> object Test {
     | def produces(f: String => Any): Boolean = true
     | def produces(x: () => Any): Boolean = false
     | }
defined object Test

scala> Test.produces(x => 5)
res9: Boolean = true

scala> Test.produces(5)
<console>:12: error: overloaded method value produces with alternatives:
  (x: () => Any)Boolean <and>
  (f: String => Any)Boolean
 cannot be applied to (Int)
       Test.produces(5)
            ^

scala> Test.produces(() => 5)
res11: Boolean = false
```